# It is possible to create a ToggleButton without text?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, togglebutton

i want to create a android default `ToggleButton` like this: [image]

but i want to create it without TEXT

I tryed with this code:

```
ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton(map);
tb.setText(null);
tb.setTextOn(null);
tb.setTextOff(null);
```

But it is leaving a empty space in the top of the horizontal green bar.

I dont want that empty space, i only want the horizontal green bar.

How to achieve it?

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The empty space in the top is caused by the 2 Ninepatch (`btn_toggle_off.9.png` and `btn_toggle_on.9.png` ) used in default toggleButton style.

To perfectly center the horizontal bar, you must create a new style for ToggleButton that will use two new ninepatch derived form original.

Edit:
Method requiring minimal XML:

- create your two ninepatches for your togglebutton, name it: `my_btn_toggle`_on and `my_btn_toggle_off`
- in drawable folder, create `my_btn_toggle.xml`:

  ```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_toggle_off" />
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_toggle_on" />
  </selector>
  ```
- in your code, add `tb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_btn_toggle)` :

  ```
  ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton(map);
  tb.setText(null);
  tb.setTextOn(null);
  tb.setTextOff(null);
  tb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_btn_toggle)
  ```

Comment: can you explain how to create that style and how to add it?? all with java code, Pableras is not using XML for designing the tooglebutton

Comment: I don't think it is possible to achieve without XML. (Pableras doesn't explicitly say he wants in java code only). I edited my answer with a method requiring minimal xml (perhaps useful).

Answer (score 20):

Just set following things:

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/tbtn1" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/bg_check"
 android:textOn="" 
 android:textOff="" 
 android:text="" />
```

And, the style xml, if you need...

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_checked="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/bg_check_on" /> <!-- pressed -->

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_check_off" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 13):

Using

```
<ToggleButton
    ...
    android:textOff="@null"
    android:textOn="@null"
    android:textSize="0dp" />
```

will not only make the text go away, but also get rid of the empty space where it would otherwise be shown.

Comment: Correct answer, and not is needed android:textSize="0dp"

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I thought so

```
android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fill style XML like this.. the magic is text color as transparent...

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textOff="blabla"
android:textOn="blablabla"
android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@drawable/boutmediumrouge"

/>
```

Comment: add some description to your answer on, how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but you could try `tb.setTextSize(0);` if you're just trying to hide the extra space on top. May need to set the textOn/textOff to an empty string: `tb.setTextOn("");`

EDIT: I better option would be to create your own custom button by `extend`ing `Button`, hold the state (see this SO post for pressed/unpressed states: [Pressed android button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019367/pressed-android-button-state)) and find the assets to set as the appropriate state...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/setting_tb"
                style="@style/style_setting_tb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much more hassle-free to use a `CheckBox` instead of the `ToggleButton`. They have the same states and thus achieve the same functionality, but you can easily change the `CheckBox` appearence by defining its `<android:button="@drawable/...">` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tooglebutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textOff="off"
        android:textOn="on"
        android:textSize="0dp"
       />
```

Comment: Include some explanation, please.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Layout File.xml

```
       <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/check"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In main activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ToggleButton mic = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    mic.setTextOff(null);
    mic.setTextOn(null);
    mic.setText(null);
```

check.xml which is used by layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mic_on"
        android:state_checked="true">

    </item>
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mic_off"
        android:state_checked="false">

    </item>
```

These lines are those what you are looking for

```
    mic.setTextOff(null);
    mic.setTextOn(null);
    mic.setText(null);
```