# How to change indicator color in Toggle Button ( Android)

Tags: android, togglebutton, indicator

Hi every body I want to use toggle button but  with different indicator color (like green or red), How to change the color of indicator .

[See default indicator on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHRXK.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are going to have to create 2 custom images of the button and then use a drawable xml as the background.

For Example:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="Toggle Button OFF"
    android:textOn="Toggle Button ON "
    android:onClick="onToggleButtonClick" />
```

Then the btntoggle_selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

bg_selected and bg_normal are just images like 9-patch.

[See the Android developer guide on 9-patch images](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use theme if changes are not big.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToggleButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And here you can use this new theme on ToggleButton.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_caps_lock_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:textOff="@string/keyboard_caps_lock"
    android:textOn="@string/keyboard_caps_lock"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToggleButton" />
```

Comment: how do you change the background color as well, without changing the  bar on the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was marked a duplicate though Switch is not the same things a ToggleButton, in Android. 
[How to change color of the toggle button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978880/how-to-change-color-of-the-toggle-button)
Both do inherit from `CompoundButton`; but have some different methods and customization support.
The `setBackground` posted elsewhere does not work to change the thumb or the border. Below is an example to change the color of the border based on 
[How set background drawable programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="3dp" />
<stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#000000" /> </shape>
```

and then in code:

```
if(!isChecked) {
    buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_for_toggle_button);
}
```

So, by setting the background then one can change the appearance. To change the entire color of the interior then one could add more the drawable XML above; such as adding this to make the inside turn green:

```
<gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00FF00"
    android:angle="270" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is a XML file**

```
<Toggle Button
    android:id="@+id/my_location"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:theme="@style/ToggleButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

**Set this style in your value-> style file**

```
<style name="ToggleButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How do you change the background color as well ?

Answer (score 0):

When I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212773/3340706) answer above like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToggleButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/red</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

my entire toggle button background become red.

If you want to change only bottom border colors you may use instead:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToggleButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```