# Android Studio: change highlight color of a toggle button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-togglebutton

I succeded to change the text color of a toggle so when it is selected it turns to red. Now, where or how can I change the color of the "highlight" line there's at the bottom of the toggle? In my case now it's blue but I'd like to change it to red as the text.

Thanks alot, Diego

[actual toggle_button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1SGM.png)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978880/how-to-change-color-of-the-toggle-button