# How custom toggleButton on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, togglebutton

I want to customize my togglebutton so that they receive this:
[image] but for now I can not change my style

I do not see how to add a background. When I do a `tb.background = "#FF0000"`

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what to do to fix your problem:

```
tb.background = "#FF0000"
```

> "Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Drawable! was expected"

Backgrounds must be of type `Drawable` (ignore the exclamation mark for now but it basically means that Kotlin can't infer if the Drawable has to be null or non-null).

You have passed a `String` as a background - hence the type mismatch.

To fix it, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978880/how-to-change-color-of-the-toggle-button) and adapt one of the answers there.

Comment: Mind: that's a **toggle button**, and change of backgroudColor in toggle buttons would change the background of the button, rather than the ToggleButton's on/off state colors.

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev thanks I didn't see it was a ToggleButton. But I'm hoping the OP can be empowered to solve this one themselves as well

Comment: I generate a list of togglebutton in the block RadioGroup so I do not see how I can do without going through the kotlin