# How can I change color of icon in icon-only toggle button in my case?

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I am using Material Design and I have a problem with it.
I have a group `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup` which includes icon-only toggle buttons with style `@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly`.
I am using style from [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#toggle-button):

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
```

There is screenshot how it looks: [without selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elMQa.png) and [selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXkaj.png).
When button is selected icon has colorPrimary color. But I wish each button has its own color when selected (e.g. 1st button - green, 2nd - yellow etc.) I tried to use tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978880/how-to-change-color-of-the-toggle-button), but it causes an error. iconColor, tint etc. cause errors too. Probably 'cause I am using Material Style... How can I change icon's color in icon-only toggle button? Not necessarily change color only when button is selected, I would be happy if button will be green before selection and will have colorPrimary when selected.

Comment: upd. icons for button are created with colors that I need. However are grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be happy if button will be green before selection and will have colorPrimary when selected.

The icon is gray because the default color is tinted with `android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"`.

You can change it overriding in the style the **`iconTint`** attribute:

```
     <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
    
         <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton               
         style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly.Green"
         />
    
         <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly.Red"
         />
```

where:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly.Green">
    <item name="iconTint">@color/icon_tint_selector</item>
</style>
```

with a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="@color/green500" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/> <!-- this color -->
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: But this style (@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly) is common for all icon-only toggle buttons... And therefore all buttons will be green, but I need 1st - green, 2nd - yellow, 3rd - orange etc. I cannot create new style because it is based on material and how I understand I cannot apply different styles for buttons. Or is it not true?

Comment: About the style. You can define another style, for example `<style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly.Green">`, and just adding the `iconTint` since it extends the `Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly` and in your button just use `style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly.Green"`.
As alternative just add the `app:iconTint` in your `Button`.

Comment: I am sorry to stupid question, but that selector shall be in colors.xml?
P.S. app:iconTint does not work

Comment: @sb69lg I've updated the answer.For the selector just create a file in `res/color/` folder.

Comment: For each button new file with selector? And @color/icon_tint_selector is name of file?

Comment: "For the selector just create a file in res/color/ folder. "
It is my first project and I am using structure from example android studio project. There colors are in colors.xml and I have not that folder "color".

Comment: @sb69lg You can create that folder :-) . Since you want different colors, yes you need different files and you can use the name that you prefer.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for bothering you, I have question related to toggle buttons group. I hope you know the answer and could answer these few short questions. How can I check is any of toggle buttons in group selected? If any of buttons in group is selected then button 'Next' will be active, else button 'Next' will be inactive. Should I check each toggle button or there is a way to check group of toggle buttons?