# Button color won't change after modifying background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm building my first Android app which is modeled after the default iOS / OS X calculator app. [image: iOS calculator]

And the current layout looks like this

[image]

In my layout i've modified the background of the number keys, but now when they are clicked the background color won't change to a darker grey like the default behavior. Is this something I need to add to `@drawable` resource? And is there anyway to modify the layout so that it fills the device screen and not leave empty space at the bottom?

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$CalculatorFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffd3d3d3"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:textSize="65sp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#545454"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:text="@string/AC"
            android:id="@+id/AC"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/plusminus"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:id="@+id/plusminus"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/percent"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:id="@+id/percent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/div"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FF9900"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/nine"
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/eight"
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mult"
            android:text="@string/mult"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FF9900"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/six"
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/minus"
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FF9900"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FF9900"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/dec"
            android:id="@+id/dec"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/equal"
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FF9900"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

using padding option and change relatvilayout

```
<Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$CalculatorFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffd3d3d3"
android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:fontFamily="helvetica"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#545454"
    android:layout_weight="0.15" />
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:padding ="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:text="@string/AC"
        android:id="@+id/AC"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/plusminus"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:id="@+id/plusminus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/percent"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:id="@+id/percent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/div"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FF9900"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding ="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/nine"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/eight"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/seven"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mult"
        android:text="@string/mult"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FF9900"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding ="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/six"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/five"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/four"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FF9900"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding ="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/three"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/two"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FF9900"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/dec"
        android:id="@+id/dec"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/equal"
        android:id="@+id/equal"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#FF9900"
        android:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight` is an invalid param using a `RelativeLayout`, i might be better sticking to a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support background changes on some specific button states (pressed, activated, selected, etc.) you will have to use `selector` instead of flat color value.

So for example for button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="@string/six"
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:fontFamily="helvetica"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

instead of using `android:background="#e5e5e5"` you should use `android:background="@drawable/selector_grey"` and add following code as a file to your `drawable` folder:

`selector_grey.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#e5e5e5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

in this example color value `#cccccc` will be used when button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

For button pressed state there are many articles on stack overflow. This can be one to start with :
[Pressed android button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019367/pressed-android-button-state)

And for layout use weight-sum property to divide layout.